# C# Cannot model bind to new html input with type=week

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework

I'm working in c#/mvc5 and am trying to return a selected week to my controller.

In the view I have rendered an html input control with type of 'week'.  From what I gather this should return a string value indicating the week and year.  I am passing the data via a viewmodel.

I always get a null string in my controller.  **Any idea what I am doing wrong?** I have found very little on the html5 input using the week type.

**Here is the View:**

```
@model JoscoConnect.ViewModels.NewTransactionViewModel
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Transaction</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Transaction", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Week, new { type = "week"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.trustedFile)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.trustedFile, new { type = "file" })
    </div>

    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Here is the ViewModel:**

```
namespace JoscoConnect.ViewModels
{
    public class NewTransactionViewModel
    {
        public string Week;

        [Required,Display(Name = "Trusted File")]
        public HttpPostedFileBase trustedFile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Here is the controller action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewTransactionViewModel newTransactionViewModel)
{
    string week = newTransactionViewModel.Week.ToString();

    TrustedImport trustedImport = new TrustedImport();
    bool result = trustedImport.CheckFileExists("test1");

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was cause by not having default getters and setters in the view model.

When I change `public string Week;` to `public string Week {get; set;}` it works fine.

Comment: Just a note -- the difference is that one is a field and the other a property. Default getter/setter is just a way to define a property.